# JavaFX LoadException while loading FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Every time I ran JavaFX app I encounter the error below.

```
15:11:52.778 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR org.fhl.Manifesto - javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/ManGenFX/target/classes/dataController.fxml
/C:/ManGenFX/target/classes/ManifestoMain.fxml:7
```

But it only happens if I add the initialize method on Main Controller.

```
    public class MainController{

        @FXML
        GenerateController genCont;

        @FXML
        private Pane generatePane;
        @FXML
        AnchorPane mainFx;

        private Node source;

    //Other Button, TextFields and Labels declaration

    @FXML
    private void browseFile(ActionEvent x) {
    //Browse file definition
    }

    @FXML
    private void savePath(ActionEvent x) {
    //Save file definition
    }

//Problem with this method
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Initialize generate controller panel");
        logger.info("Initialize generate controller panel");

        genCont.init(this);

        }
    }
```

If I remove the initialize method on MainController class it will not throw any error but nothing happens either if I click on the generate button which is defined in GenerateController class below.

```
public class GenerateController {
    @FXML
    Button btnGenerate;
    @FXML
    Pane paneGen;

    @FXML
    public void generateMan(ActionEvent event) {

//generateMan body when Generate button is clicked

    }

    public void init(MainController mc) {
        System.out.println("Init mainControl");
        mainControl = mc;

    }

public void validate() {
//Definition of method body here
  }
}
```

This is the main Class

```
public class Man extends Application {

    private Stage mainStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        this.mainStage = primaryStage;
        this.mainStage.setTitle("Manifest");

        try{

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ManifestoMain.fxml"));

            Scene sMain = new Scene(root);

            mainStage.setScene(sMain);

            mainStage.show();

        }catch(IOException ioE) {
            logger.error(ioE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Also, I placed my dataController.fxml, ManifestoMain.fxml, and generateView.fxml under resources folder but it don't have any problem accessing the files. Appreciate help on this.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace in the question. Can you also post the FXML files, and indicate which is line 7 in `manifestoMain.fxml`?

Comment: @James_D unfortunately that is the only error I receive when I hit run which is a bit weird.

Comment: Add `ioE.printStackTrace()` to your catch block and see if it gives you the complete error. Probably your logger is configured somehow not to generate the full stack trace.

Comment: where do I need to place it?

Comment: In the catch block.

Comment: The field name `genCont` in your main controller looks wrong, but there's no way to know unless you provide the requested information.

Comment: @James_D thanks for helping out... i did not continue having multiple controller because it was already taking too much time(time constraints with management) just figuring out this stuff. I just did one controller and reference POJOs to do the backend processing so its one big Interface (FXML file) with lots of buttons and fields. appreciate all your help! maybe some other time I'll try to study multiple controllers.